# Where are core dumps written on Mac?

Tags: macos, unix, signals, coredump

On Mac OS X, if I send SIGQUIT to my C program, it terminates, but there is no core dump file.

Do you have to manually enable core dumps on Mac OS X (how?), or are they written to somewhere else instead of the working directory?

Comment: Instead of complaining you could rephrase it - in fact your title does not even have a verb in it. I would gladly upvote your question because I'm interested about the subject. Still I think that the question is not following the quality required by SO. 
I even have related question regarding coredump
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207233/how-to-enable-full-coredumps-on-os-x

By the way, coredumps are to be located in `/cores` but do look in this folder using the terminal and root account.

Comment: @Sorin A suggestion is not a problem, pettiness is.

Comment: @Sorin FYI 'are' is a (linking) verb.  Not that it really matters here, but if we are criticizing grammar let's get it right ;) http://examples.yourdictionary.com/reference/examples/examples-of-linking-verbs.html

Comment: Related: [How to generate core dumps in Mac OS X?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412156/how-to-generate-core-dumps-in-mac-os-x).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a great explanation by `Quinn “The Eskimo!”` on Apple's forums
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/694233

I roughly followed that guide. Here are the steps that I did.

Grant write all access to the `/cores` dir

```bash
PROMPT> ls -la / | grep cores
drwxr-xr-x    2 root  wheel    64 Dec  8  2021 cores
PROMPT> sudo chmod 1777 /cores
PROMPT> ls -la / | grep cores
drwxrwxrwt    2 root  wheel    64 Dec 21 23:29 cores
```

Set size of core file

```bash
PROMPT> ulimit -c unlimited
```

Compile and sign the program

```bash
PROMPT> cargo build --release -p my-crashing-program
PROMPT> /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :com.apple.security.get-task-allow bool true" tmp.entitlements
PROMPT> codesign -s - -f --entitlements tmp.entitlements my-crashing-program
```

Run the program

```bash
PROMPT> my-crashing-program
thread 'main' panicked at 'boom', my-crashing-program/src/main.rs:74:5
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
dumping core for pid 80995
zsh: quit       my-crashing-program
```

Now there is a `core` file

```bash
PROMPT> ls /cores
core.80995
```

Also Apple's `Console` app has a list with `Crash Reports`.

Comment: This is the only procedure that works in modern MacOs versions.

Comment: Also referenced [here](https://nasa.github.io/trick/howto_guides/How-to-dump-core-file-on-MacOS.html)

Answer (score 98):

It seems they are suppressed by default. Running

```
$ ulimit -c unlimited
```

Will enable core dumps for the current terminal, and it will be placed in `/cores` as `core.PID`. When you open a new session, it will be set to the default value again.

Comment: This seems to now work anymore with modern MacOs versions. @neoneye 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74882522/213871) works, also referenced [here](https://nasa.github.io/trick/howto_guides/How-to-dump-core-file-on-MacOS.html)

Answer (score 41):

On macOS, your crash dumps are automatically handled by [Crash Reporter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crash_Reporter).

You can find backtrace files by executing [Console](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Console_%28OS_X%29) and going to *User Diagnostic Reports* section (under 'Diagnostic and Usage Information' group) or you can locate them in `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports`.

You can also check where dumps are generated by monitoring `system.log` file, e.g.

```
tail -f /var/log/system.log | grep crash
```

The actual *core* dump files you can find in `/cores`.

See also:

- [How to generate core dumps in Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412156/how-to-generate-core-dumps-in-mac-os-x)
- [Technical Note TN2118: Kernel Core Dumps](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2004/tn2118.html).

Answer (score 15):

Additionally, the /cores directory must exist and the user running the program must have write permissions on it.

Comment: I just cleaned it up, taking 186GB of my space!

Answer (score 13):

The answer above,

> ulimit -c unlimited

works -- but be sure to run that in the same terminal from which you will run the program that dumps core.  You need to run the ulimit command first.

Answer (score 12):

by default, specific directories in mac osx are hidden. you might want to enable this feature in the terminal and then the core dump should be visible within the directory /cores.

> defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE

Comment: Thank you. I was browsing with Terminal (ls -lah), but that's a useful tip anyway.