# How to enable full coredumps on OS X?

Tags: macos, coredump

It looks that OS X (10.6) does not generates codedumps by default.

Using the `ulimit -c unlimited` is not a good solution because ulimit does set the limit in an environment variable. This will work only for console applications executed from the shell that executed ulimit. If you have a gui application this will not work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can enable core dumps and then launch your GUI app from the command line using [open](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html).

```
$ ulimit -c unlimited
$ open /Applications/Address\ Book.app
```

I just looked at [TN2124](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/technotes/tn2004/tn2124.html#SECCOREDUMPS) and it suggests a similar approach, only without using open and just launching the app directly, e.g.

```
$ ulimit -c unlimited
$ /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit
```

Comment: This doesn't always work, please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x

Comment: That discussion appears to be about inheriting environment variables. Try the TN2124 technique above and see if that works for you.