# Core Dump is is not working

Tags: c, macos, segmentation-fault, gdb, coredump

When I run programs with segfaults I get an error message **Segmentation fault: 11**. For some reason, I'm not getting the (core dumped) message. I tried running the shell command `ulimit -c unlimited`, but I still get the same error and it doesn't say core dumped. I'm new to GDB so I tried it with a simple program:

```
/* coredump.c */
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
  int *point = NULL;
  *point = 0;
  return 0;
}
```

But when I compile using:

```
gcc coredump.c -g -o coredump
```

And run it, it still says `segfault: 11`

Is it still creating a core dump somewhere I don't know about? I want to be able to use **gdb coredump core**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable full coredumps on OS X?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207233/how-to-enable-full-coredumps-on-os-x)

Answer (score 2):

Look at this link:

- [How to generate a core dump in Linux when a process gets a segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965/generate-a-core-dump-in-linux)

Options include:

- ulimit -c unlimited (default = 0: no core files generated)
- the directory for the dump must be writable. By default this is the current directory of the process, but that may be changed by setting /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern.
- in some conditions, the kernel value in /proc/sys/fs/suid_dumpable may prevent the core to be generated.
- "man core" for other options
- `find / -name core -print 2> /dev/null` to search your filesystem for core files

I *presume* you're running Linux, and I *presume* you're executing the .exe in a directory where you have write permissions.

So my top two guesses would be 1) "ulimit -c unlimited" isn't getting set, or is being overridden, or 2) the core files are being generated, but going "somewhere else".

The above suggestions should help.  Please post back what you find!

Comment: Thanks for the link! I am using OSX, and when i checked the man page for core, it said that dumps are disabled by default under Darwin/Max OS X to re-enable core dumps, a privelaged user must edit **/etc/launchd.conf**, but I don't see that file under /etc..?

Comment: @DanMoore  - Check out these links: [setting-environment-variables-in-os-x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/),  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2004/tn2124.html, [how-to-enable-full-coredumps-on-os-x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207233/).  Note that `/etc/launchd.conf` might not exist.  Just create one, per the example in one of the replies the first link.

Comment: It worked! I checked out the first link you sent me. i created a new config file in /etc, wrote the line **limit core unlimited**, rebooted my mac, and now all my segfault error messages say (core dumped)! The core file itself can be found in /cores.   Thanks!!

Comment: @DanMoore - Cool: thank you for the good word!  Please mark this reply "accepted" if it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running the program that crashes from the shell, then you should follow the guidelines in Apple's Tech Note [TN2124](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2124/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003391-CH1-SECCOREDUMPS), which I found out about in in the answer to [SO2207233](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207233/how-to-enable-full-coredumps-on-os-x).

There are a few key points:

1. You need to set `ulimit -c unlimited` in `bash` (same effect, different command in `tcsh`).
2. You need to set the permissions on the `/cores` directory so that you can create files in it.  The default permissions are 1775; you need 1777.  The 1 indicates the sticky bit is set.
3. The core dumps are then created in `/cores` suffixed with a PID (`/cores/core.5312`, for example).

If you want programs launched graphically to dump core when they crash, then you need to create `/etc/launchd.conf` if it does not already exist, and add a line `limit core unlimited` to the file.  Again, see the information in the Tech Note for more details.

---

Watch it; core dumps are huge!  Consider this not very complicated or big program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int *i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    printf("i = %d, j = %d, i / j = %d\n", *i, j, *i / j);
    return 0;
}
```

The core dump from this is nearly 360 MB.

Comment: that's really interesting. Why is that core dump so big?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes core files are not store in current directory and may follow a different naming rule

```
sysctl -a | grep kern.core
```

may give hints to where your core files are stored

Comment: nothing happens when i type that command into bash :( thanks though The current directory has no core files and i looked into the /cores directory from the root and theres nothing there either.

Comment: grep kernel.core /etc/sysctl.conf ?

Answer (score 0):

Using gcc, if you add the flags:

```
gcc -g -dH
```

you should be able to generate a core dump

The -g flag produces some debugging information to use with gdb, and the -dH flag produces a core dump when there is an error

Comment: i compiled using **gcc -g -dH coredump.c**, but when I ran the a.out, no core dump message appeared :( thanks though

Comment: The message may not appear, but was there a file named coredump.dSYM, or something similar