# Bus Error - How can I find out where program died?

Tags: c++, qt4

"Bus Error" doesn't tell me much so I want to access the core file to find out where it went wrong.  I try to do this:

```
(gdb) core core
/this/is/my/directory/Program/core: No such file or directory
(gdb)
```

but it says there is no directory.  I compile my program using Qt on mac and it does not produce anything called 'core'.  Any advice on how to debug this?

Thank you.

Comment: Used to linux? Have you tried attaching a debugger? If you're using QtCreator as an IDE it has one built in then you can see the callstack, set break points, and debug your application normally.

Comment: I think this will be helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080918/where-are-core-dumps-written-to-in-mac-os-x

Answer (score 3):

I don't use a Mac, but it seems like core files are either suppressed by default or written to a dedicated directory. You could copy the core file to your program directory and invoke gdb with the excecutable and core file name:

[Where are core dumps written in Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080918/where-are-core-dumps-written-to-in-mac-os-x)

GDB: http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/

```
gdb <program_name> <core_file_name>
```