# How to generate core dumps in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, coredump

It seems like I can not generate core dumps in Mac OS X 10.6.8.

```
$ ulimit -c unlimited
$ ./a.out 
Hello world!
Segmentation fault
$ find ~/ -type f -name core 

# ls -la /cores/
total 0
drwxrwxr-t@  2 root  admin    68 24 jui  2010 .
drwxrwxr-t  31 root  admin  1122 17 oct 15:52 ..
```

My current directory, my HOME and /cores/ remain empty…

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where are core dumps written](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080918/where-are-core-dumps-written-to-in-mac-os-x). /core/ may contain files hidden, hence set `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE `

Comment: Thanks for your answer Bort, but I've already seen this thread ; it's not about hidden files.

Comment: Apple saves core files in the `/cores` directory. Ensure the permissions on the directory are set properly. See Apple's [Mac OS X Debugging Magic](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2124/_index.html). Also, don't you need a leading dot "." so the changes are applied to the current shell and all child shells?

Comment: Or you can just enable core dumps in your terminal without the restart: http://mindarray.org/techlog/gdb-debugging.html

Comment: And if you want to not have to use /cores you could always make a symlink in your home directory (or wherever you wish) to point to /cores though this would only add a way to reference the file.

Comment: Archive of: [mindarray.org/techlog/gdb-debugging.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20120113040608/http://www.mindarray.org/techlog/gdb-debugging.html)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

By default, crashes are reported into `.crash` files which can be found in `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports` (system-wide) and `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports` (user). These files can be opened by using *Console* app, in *User* or *System Reports*. The `.crash` files are in plain text format and should include relevant information about the crash.

---

In order to activate the full core dumps, make sure that `/cores` directory has write permissions for the current user (test by: `touch /cores/test && rm /cores/test`). In addition, make sure that you don't have any limits on core file sizes by:

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

The name of the core dump file is in format: `core`.`PID`.

If the directory is hidden, you can show the hidden files by:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
```

You can test that by the following commands:

```
sleep 100 &
killall -SIGSEGV sleep
```

which should say extra `(core dumped)`, after *Segmentation fault* message.

The core dump files should be found by default in `/cores` directory.

---

Example by commands:

```
$ ulimit -c unlimited
$ sleep 100 &
$ killall -SIGSEGV sleep # Then press Enter few times till below message is shown
[1]+  Segmentation fault: 11  (core dumped) sleep 100
$ ls /cores
core.13652
$ lldb -c /cores/core.*
(lldb) target create --core "/cores/core.13652"
Core file '/cores/core.13652' (x86_64) was loaded.
(lldb) bt
* thread #1, stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
  * frame #0: 0x00007fffa7d13fde libsystem_kernel.dylib`__semwait_signal + 10
    frame #1: 0x00007fffa7c9ab92 libsystem_c.dylib`nanosleep + 199
    frame #2: 0x000000010c090002 sleep`rpl_nanosleep + 128
```

---

See also: [Technical Note TN2118 - Kernel Core Dumps](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2004/tn2118.html).

Comment: This is true, but not as useful as a true core dump; if you need more information on _why_ the application crashed (and the context surrounding the crash), there's just no substitute for a core dump if you can't replicate the crash scenario on your machine for any reason.

Comment: @fraveydank I've simplified the answer to avoid confusion. The OS X have its own format of core dumps and they've a proper context. These core dump files can be found in `/cores`.

Comment: These core dump instructions no longer seem to work on macOS 10.13. I did the `ulimit` thing and verified that `/cores` is writable, but no core appears in `/cores`, and no "(core dumped)" message appears with the "Segmentation fault" message (https://gist.github.com/apjanke/756bdae743e6a220b49d910bd4baf4f0) Any ideas how to enable this for newer versions of macOS?

Comment: This answer worked for me on 10.14 just now and produced a cores file `/cores/core.19098` for a SIGSEGV.

Comment: Launch the process to be dumped from the same terminal where `ulimit -c unlimited` has been set. E.g. to core dump TextEdit, launch it from the command line using the full path `/Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit`

Comment: Not working on 10.15.4 (using `ulimit -c unlimited` and the `sleep` test shown above).  /cores directory is world writeable, but I'm not an admin on this machine; don't know if that's related or not.

Comment: ...and just to follow up: now trying again with an admin account, it still doesn't work.

Comment: does not not work for me in 2021 with macos BigSur

Comment: 2021 works if you also sudo chown (whoami) /cores or sudo chown $(whoami) /cores

Comment: For anyone else stumbling into here, it seems /bin commands cannot generate core dumps, so the kill sleep command doesn't work to validate. This is per https://stackoverflow.com/a/60396365/410074

Answer (score 13):

You can generate core dump files on Mac Os X like this:

1. Create the file : `/etc/launchd.conf`, then :

   `echo "limit core unlimited" | sudo tee -a /etc/launchd.conf`
2. Restart your Mac.

And that's it, the core dump files are generated in the `/cores` directory. Be careful the core dump files are **large files** so when you finishing troubleshooting your code, remove them.

Comment: I did it and nothing happened differently. Is the system supposed to pick that up? Do I need to enable core dump in the JVM settings?

Comment: Is there any way to generate the core dump file at the directory of crashed program by default?

Comment: This solution also did not work for me. I followed the instructions precisely and double checked my file name and the contents of launchd.conf.

Comment: @Developer I believe there has been some sort of change in more recent versions of macOS. I tried this with another limit and it didn't seem to work. Or so I think it was a limit. Certainly I did use that file and didn't have success so maybe it had already changed in 2015.

Comment: @Jason See my comment to Developer on why this might be (though I cannot confirm that it's why I somehow suspect it's relevant).

Answer (score 12):

Apple list a number of ways to generate core dump files in their [TN2124](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2124/_index.html) or [Mac OS X Debugging Magic](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2124/_index.html).

Here's a couple of extracts:

> Prior to Mac OS X 10.4, you would enable core dumps on a system-wide
>   basis by changing the line "COREDUMPS=-NO-" in /etc/hostconfig to
>   "COREDUMPS=-YES-" and then restarting

And

```
# BSH
$ ulimit -c unlimited

# CSH
% limit coredumpsize unlimited
```

You can even do it programatically:

```
#include <sys/resource.h>

static bool EnableCoreDumps(void)
{
    struct rlimit   limit;

    limit.rlim_cur = RLIM_INFINITY;
    limit.rlim_max = RLIM_INFINITY;
    return setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE, &limit) == 0;
}
```

Comment: In `/etc/hostconfig` file the comment says: `This file is going away`, so this file would be depreciated soon. The type of preferences previously found in `hostconfig` is now contained within the launchd .plist files themselves. For example, when you turn off AFP sharing in System Preferences, it's added to the `com.apple.AppleFileServer.plist` in `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons`

Comment: I’m tempted to down vote this simply for referencing the ghastly csh... Okay not really. But that's a good point of explaining (and so csh or no I’ve up voted it) *`setrlimit()`* for those who don't know about it (I do but I suspect many do not - although I've always had `ulimit -c unlimited` enabled so never needed it for core dumps).

Answer (score 6):

On the Mac OS X Yosemite, you can enable the core dump on a per-process basis using LLDB. Assuming your process id is `51918`, run the following from bash:

```
$ lldb
(lldb) attach 51918
Process 51918 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x6bf50, 0x00007fff927c14de libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
    frame #0: 0x00007fff927c14de libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap:
->  0x7fff927c14de <+10>: retq   
    0x7fff927c14df <+11>: nop    

libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_overwrite_trap:
    0x7fff927c14e0 <+0>:  movq   %rcx, %r10
    0x7fff927c14e3 <+3>:  movl   $0x1000020, %eax

Executable module set to "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java".
Architecture set to: x86_64h-apple-macosx.

(lldb) expr long long * $limit = (long long *)malloc(16)
(lldb) expr $limit[0] = 0x7fffffffffffffff
(long long) $0 = 9223372036854775807
(lldb) expr $limit[1] = 0x7fffffffffffffff
(long long) $1 = 9223372036854775807
(lldb) expr (int)setrlimit(4, $limit)
(int) $2 = 0
(lldb) detach
Process 51918 detached
```

If you process causes a segmentation fault, you will now find a core in `/cores`. You can check this be sending a SIGABRT to your process after running the above:

```
kill -ABRT 51918
```

Please note that attaching to process owned by root won't work on recent macOSes (El Capitan and above) by default due to [System Integrity Protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection).