# Segmentation Fault: 11 on OSX python

Tags: python, macos, numpy, pandas, scipy

I'm getting an intermittant segfault in python, which really shouldn't happen. It's a heisenbug, so I haven't figured out exactly what's causing it.

I've done the search and found that there was a known problem with an older version of python, but I'm using 2.7.10 (in a virtualenv, in case that matters)

I'm using pandas (0.18.0) , scipy(0.17.0) and numpy (1.11.0), in case the problem might be in there...

Comment: Speaking for myself, a segfault in python is always in a bit of dodgy C code that I have written, probably on a Friday night.  Have you added any of your own C modules?  Or maybe used `ctypes`?

Comment: Nope... we have no home-grown C... or ctypes. Friday night code, I make no claims of. B-)

Comment: If you are on a UNIX-like system then you should get a `core` dump - you might have to do `ulimit -c unlimited` to get the file.  Using a debugger you might be able to find which executable (.so) file it came from.  You won't get much more without debug versions of python and your modules though.

Comment: It's a mac, so technically, yes. It was already unlimited, and no core.

Comment: A core dump should have been produced.  To check that it was unlimited, did you do `ulimit -c`?  (If you just do `ulimit` then the default is `-f`, which is the maximum file size, not the core dump option).

Comment: I don't seem to be able to change ulimit. ulimit -c gives 0. ulimit -c unlimited gives "operation not permitted" When I try with sudo, it doesn't error, but doesn't do anything either.

Comment: Try `ulimit -c hard`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to do anything. IT looks like crashes are handled elswehre on a mac...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like: [How to generate core dumps in Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412156/how-to-generate-core-dumps-in-mac-os-x)

might be the best way to get stack trace...it appears in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports I'm not sure if it's USEFUL, and it's not a core per se, to be put into a debugger, but it's something...