# How to analyze dmp file in Mac OS?

Tags: macos, dump

One of applications crashes from time to time and generate .dmp file.
What tool can I use to analyze this kind of files? I'd like to see the call stack etc.

Comment: Try first `file your.dmp` ; show its output in your question; then consider using `gdb yourbinary your.dmp`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2080918/841108 could be a near duplicate

Comment: Does Crash Reporter not kick in when your app crashes?  That will give you a stack trace.  You will find them in `~/Library/Logs/Diagnostic Reports` in the Console.

Comment: I haven't been able to read a Windows .dmp file (from BSOD) on macOS so I ended up installing a Windows VM.