# How can I enable coredump in macos

Tags: c++, macos

The following code can cause core dump

```
#include <cstdio>
int main(){
    printf("%d", *((int*)1));
}
```

However when I run on my mac, there is no coredump generated in `/cores`

```
calvin@CalvinPC test % ./a
zsh: segmentation fault  ./a
calvin@CalvinPC test % ls -a /cores
.   ..
```

However, I already have `ulimit -c unlimited`, and `sudo sysctl kern.coredump=1`

So, how can I cause a core dump in macos?

Comment: undefined beahvior is undefined. Your code example *can* cause something, but it can also cause anything else

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Since it already causes a segev, why does not it coredump?

Comment: oh ok, I think now I understand the question

Comment: Are you setting ulimit in the same window you run the program? According to this answer, it is for the terminal session. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2080938/4238087

Also, you should be able to use abort() to do the same but POSIX compliant.

Comment: Last time I tried, `ulimit -c unlimited` worked on macOS for me.